# String.Replace() special characters in sql query performance

Tags: c#, sql, string, performance, postgresql

I am working in postgresql 8.4. I need to insert big amount of texts 2kb each.In order to build a query i have to replace special characters like `'` with `''`.Now iam doing

```
string.Format("INSERT INTO my_table (text_col) VALUES ('{0}')", mytext.Replace("'","''"))
```

Replace operation takes 4x more time than `cmd.Execute()` of whole query according to visual studio performance sampling.  Is there any way to call `string.Replace()` or any other way to improve performance?

Comment: Use parameterized queries, your current query is vulnerable for sql injection.

Comment: is your `myText` a very long string? and how can you say `Replace` is taking time

Comment: You could have a look at HtmlEncode: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @dbw, myText is about 2kb string. I am using CPU sampling in visual studio. It shows samples. So i get 4x more samples in `string.Replace()` than `cmd.Execute()`

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way of replacing large (small strings perform slightly worse) is [Fast Token Replacement](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/298519/Fast-Token-Replacement-in-Csharp)

You will need to try it out and see how it performs for your specific use-case, other than that, I'd suggest you use a parameterized query.  Your query **may** be vulnerable to SQL-Injection, assuming you do no sanitation and it is user entered data, then it **is vulnerable**.